# can not found NODE_MODULE_VERSION 76

Tags: javascript, sqlite

`Uncaught Error: The module '\\?\D:\better-sqlite3\build\better_sqlite3.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 79. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 76. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using` npm rebuild`or`npm install`).`

but in Nodejs history releases, I can not found NODE_MODULE_VERSION 76.
[image]

[image]